# How can I toggle CSS propteries for mutliple elements efficiently?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The working solution I have is below.  But it does not scale well and looks verbose.

I want to be able to add more and more `<li>` tags with out creating so much code.

This code simply toggles a bottom border so you know what you have selected.

```
  render () {

    var style_fave;
    var style_splash;
    if (this.props.state.current === 'splash') {
      style_splash = {
        borderBottom: '3px solid #000000'
      };
      style_fave = {
        borderBottom: ''
      };
    }
    if (this.props.state.current === 'fave') {
      style_fave = {
        borderBottom: '3px solid #000000'
      };
      style_splash = {
        borderBottom: ''
      };
    }

    return (
            // ... snip
            <li style={style_fave} id="mm_top_list_item" onClick={this.clickHandler2.bind(this)}>
              <span className="menu_item">
                <img className = 'item_svg' src="_images/sv_star_5_custom.svg"/>
              </span>
            </li>
            <li style={style_splash} onClick={this.clickHandler3.bind(this)} id="nav_splash">
              <span id="nav_splash_inner" className="menu_item">SIGNON</span>
            </li>
            // ... snip
```

Comment: It's not really clear from this snippet what your end goal is. You are applying two styles to two hard coded `<li>`s. It would seem like you want to have a bunch of list items with potentially different styles based on state. Are there still only two styles here, or multiple potential styles? If so, why not create a new React component that atomizes this behavior that way the outer component need not be concerned with it.

Comment: I'ts just a simple menu like the one stack overflow uses. ( Questions, Developer Jobs, Tags, etc. )  When you click on a list item the bottom border is created so you know what tab you are on.  I'm not sure what you mean by `atomize` it?

Comment: make it more atomic or component oriented :)
So based on that, it sounds like their are only two states - active and inactive. You can make a component that takes an `active` prop (Boolean). If true, include the active style.

Answer (score 0):

try code like this, which really just extracts the commonalities to the top

```
// outside your class definition
const liStyle = {};
const selectedLiStyle = {...liStyle, borderBottom: "3px solid black" };

// snip

render() {
  const c = this.props.state.current;

  return (
     // snip
     <li style={c==="fave" ? selectedLiStyle : liStyle } ... />
     <li style={c==="splash" ? selectedLiStyle : liStyle } ... />
     ...
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to separate concerns as much as possible. Here is a contrived example of what I was trying to get at in my comment:

```js
// something from state
const navItemState = [{
    name: 'Questions',
    active: false,
  }, {
    name: 'Posts',
    active: true,
  }, {
    name: 'Jobs',
    active: false
}]

// nav item that encapsulates its own logic and style based on state
const NavItem = ({active, name}) => (
  <li style={active ? {borderBottom: '1px solid orange'} : {}}>{name}</li>
)

// map over nav items to generate a nav
const Nav = () => (
  <ul>
    {navItemState.map(item => (
      <NavItem active={item.active} name={item.name} />
    ))}
  </ul>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Nav />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Basically, you have list item metadata stored somewhere - could be an external state store, could be component state, could be based on route (I'm not sure of your app setup). The important point is, you want each component to manage itself. Instead of having a huge render function that hard codes each list item and then determines the styles that should go in each one, try to generalize as much as possible so you have a concept like "active". If each list item can only occupy two states, you are looking at a single boolean to control that on each one. Once you have abstracted all common logic into the `NavItem` component, you can simply pass a prop to each one rather than worrying about passing an entire style object with logic every time you want to add a new list item.

Answer (score 0):

A more 'react' way is to have the a component manage the state of which Menu Item is currently selected. This then flows down as a prop to the menu item, and it determines how to update it's presentation.

When a menu item is clicked, it's onClick calls the parents MenuClicked function to set a new state and the menu items can update themselves as needed.

State and Props are fundamental to how react works and are the the most import thing to understand in the beginning.

*Note: If you are, or decide to, use react-router to manage routes, it has a built in NavLink component that makes styling navigation bars and links easy.*

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeMenuItem: ''
    }
  }
  menuClicked(e) {
    this.setState({activeMenuItem: e.target.innerHTML})
  }
  isActive(item) {
    return item === this.state.activeMenuItem
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu>
          <MenuItem label="Home" activeItem={this.isActive("Home")} onClick={(e) => this.menuClicked(e)} />
          <MenuItem label="Details" activeItem={this.isActive("Details")} onClick={(e) => this.menuClicked(e)}  />
          <MenuItem label="About" activeItem={this.isActive("About")} onClick={(e) => this.menuClicked(e)}  />
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const MenuItem = props => {
  let styles = {
        listStyle: "none",
        display: "inline-flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        padding: "0 10px"
      }
  
  if (props.activeItem) {
    styles = {...styles, borderBottom: "3px solid darkgray"}
  }
  
  return (
    <li
      style={styles}
      onClick={(e) => props.onClick(e)}
    >
      {props.label}
    </li>
  );
};

const Menu = props => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: 75,
        backgroundColor: "lightgray",
        display: "flex"
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```